# Ng-grid search bar in the grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Right now I am using ng-grid and the grid option, `showFilter: true`

This places a triangle drop down in the top right corner of the grid, which when clicked pops up a search bar.

Is there a way with ng-grid to have the search bar directly visible in the grid without the need to click the triangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just make a input text wherever you want in your view with your ng-grid:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="outside_search_text" placeholder="Search"
                                       class="form-control" data-ng-change="search()">
<div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions">
                        </div>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.sortOptions = {
        fields      : ['id'],
        directions  : ['DESC']
    };


    $scope.totalServerItems         = 0;
    $scope.gridOptions['sortInfo']  = $scope.sortOptions;

    $scope.gridOptions['columnDefs'] = [
        {field          : 'name', displayName: 'Name'}
    ];


    $scope.refresh = function() {
        var p = {
            searchText      : {name: $scope.outside_search_text},
            pageNumber      : $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
            pageSize        : $scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,
            sortField       : $scope.sortOptions.fields,
            sortDirection   : $scope.sortOptions.directions
        };

        YourServices.getAll(p).then(function(response) {
            var content = getResponseData(response);

            $scope.totalServerItems = content.count;
            $scope.myData           = content.result_set;

            if (content['result_set'].length > 0) {
                //whatever
            } else {
                //whatever
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I changed the ng-model for the input as "filterText" and this worked for me. Thanks.